# Is .net core available on Azure web apps?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, .net-core

Is .net core(dnxcore50) available on Azure web apps? I can only see 3.5/4.6 available in the app settings menu. I mean not officially(as it is rc now) but for testing purposes. Thanks.

Comment: I didn't think dnxcore needed to be installed on the server. All you need is the `HttpPlatformHandler` installed on IIS. My understanding is that the HttpPlatformHandler has been installed for Azure websites.

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/vs/alm/Build/azure/deploy-aspnet5

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is available. You can deploy an ASP.NET 5 CoreCLR based application to Azure Websites. Even Platform Handler is available.

If you're using VS2015 then you can simply publish from VS.

Answer (score 1):

Main .net core feature it's it doesn't require installing on server. We can simply copy it with your application.

quote from [docs.asp.net](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/conceptual-overview/dotnetcore.html):

> One of the key benefits of .NET Core is its portability. You can
>   package and deploy the CoreCLR with your application, eliminating your
>   application’s dependency on an installed version of .NET (e.g. .NET
>   Framework on Windows). You can host multiple applications side-by-side
>   using different versions of the CoreCLR, and upgrade them
>   individually, rather than being forced to upgrade all of them
>   simultaneously.