# When will Azure App Services use .NET 5.0 core?

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2015, azure-web-app-service

Right now it seems you can only create a 'Web Site' with ASP.NET 5.0. The options for 'App Services' Are under .NET 4.6. Is this correct?  Will 'App Services' have a 5.0 template in the future ?

Comment: Some may find answers here if you're getting HTTP Error 500.31 - ANCM Failed to Find Native Dependencies https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65097886/azure-app-service-unable-to-target-5-0-100-http-error-500-31-ancm-failed-to-fi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They eventually will but you should not need to wait. One of the goals behind ASP.Net 5 Core was to make it so the project was encapsulated and did not need the .Net framework installed to run, for environments like Linux and Mac. .Net 5 Core can also run along side other .Net Framework versions without impacting them. Because of this design you should be able to develop for .Net 5.0 Core, build, and then deploy to App Services with no problems.

Comment: But the templates there now are NOT for 5.0 right? So I guess  I would have to take the 'Web Site' template and adjust it to be a 'App Service/API app' ?  How would that work ?

Comment: You could take the template for a Web Site and do the needed changes to make it an app service or an API or you could use the empty template and build from scratch. It would work just like if you took a different template from 4.6 and modified it. The templates just setup the most commonly used feature for you to save you a few minutes of setup, nothing stops you from modifying them to suit your needs.

Comment: But I thought alopt of things change in 5.0.. Its not just use a .net 4.6 template and flip a switch and it is 5.0 is it ?

Comment: If you use the .Net 5.0 website template and mod it or an empty 5.0 template and build it up you will be fine.

Comment: ok... So for now just try to mod the 'web site' template.. and I assume templates for other things will come out eventually

Comment: Once it comes out of RC and into full release there should be templates for everything. For now either build from the empty or modify the web site template

Answer (score 1):

Possible duplicate: [Is .net core available on Azure web apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33966114/is-net-core-available-on-azure-web-apps)

The short answer is that the idea behind .NET core is that you deploy it yourself as part of your application, and you can certainly do this.  The .NET selection in the management portal is really just specifying the default framework version that the worker process uses, but that's only relevant when you're writing ASP.NET 4x or legacy ASP.NET web apps.

Comment: So will there be templates in VS2015 for example a '.NET 5.0 core App Service/API'... or am I thinking about it all wrong ?

Comment: Quite possibly (though I don't know firsthand if there will be)! But at the end of the day, VS2015 is just creating a web app which can be deployed anywhere (including App Service). Whether it uses a certain version of the .NET Framework or whether it uses .NET core doesn't really concern App Service.  BTW, you can make template suggestions to the product team here: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287595-api-apps.

Comment: I think all the recent changes how they categorize App Services/Mobile Services/API has me confused.. Does Azure consider them all just to be a 'Web Site' now ? it is unclear.. I guess I can just start with th e'Web Site' template and extend that.. or would I take a 4.6 templte and somehow convert it to 5.0.. I'm confused.. I guess someone eventually will make a starter template

Comment: Under the covers, these are all just web apps in App Service. API apps and Mobile apps are really just templates for helping guide you in the right direction. Technically you can start from a web app and build an API app.  As far as VS is concerned, I don't know their roadmap, but I would expect that at some point there will be a VS template for creating an API app using ASP.NET 5. There are a few things that don't yet work 100% correctly with API apps on .NET core (built-in App Service auth is one example) but I expect that will be corrected around the time ASP.NET 5 releases.