# Azure App Service Unable to Target 5.0.100 HTTP Error 500.31 - ANCM Failed to Find Native Dependencies

Tags: azure-web-app-service

"The specified version of Microsoft.NetCore.App or Microsoft.AspNetCore.App was not found."

Everything I've read led me to believe that .NET 5 is ready to be used for an app service. So I made the necessary changes and merged my code. The build (pipeline) went find. The release made it to the App Service. But for some reason the machine with the App service does not have .NET 5 installed. My question is, am I wrong in assuming that Azure is raeady to host .NET 5 applications. If it is possible, then how do I do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deploy ASP.NET Core 5 app to Azure App Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64777919/deploy-asp-net-core-5-app-to-azure-app-service). Note: This is my question (and answer), but it's addressing the exact same error, and proposes the exact same solution outlined below.

Answer (score 2):

App Service DOES support .NET 5, but the verbiage on the config page is confusing. You need to set the app service to use '.NET' instead of '.NET Core'. Follow these steps:

Go to the App Service in Azure

- under Settings, click on 'Configuration'
- then 'General settings'
- Change 'Stack' from '.NET Core' to '.NET'
- Set '.NET Framework version' to '.NET 5 (Early Access)'
- Save

I'm not sure why they put .NET 5 under the .NET Framework dropdown or why it's still labeled "early access" but this should hopefully get you up and running again.

Answer (score -1):

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/troubleshoot-azure-iis?view=aspnetcore-5.0#50031-ancm-failed-to-find-native-dependencies) is clear on that error.
Try to install [NET 5](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/5.0)

Comment: Azure App Service is a PaaS solution, hence it is not possible to install anything